# MS SQL - Count the occurrences of a word in a field

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, split

I'm having a column in a table which contains data as shown below

- Oranges
- Apple
- Oranges, Apple
- Mango

I need to find the occurences and the name of the fruit and return the output in two columns

Oranges - Oranges(2)
Apple - Apple(2)
Mango - Mango(1)

Is it possible to combine LIKE and COUNT function to get the desired results.

Comment: What's your sql-server version?

Comment: SQL Server 2012

Comment: Are the values which appear in the column known?  That is, do you know you will only ever have the values Oranges, Apple, and Mango?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen this is not known.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) support from *sql-server 2016* if your version lower than 2016,you can try to write a split function to split your column by `,`

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_split ( @stringToSplit VARCHAR(MAX) )
RETURNS
 @returnList TABLE ([Name] [nvarchar] (500))
AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @pos INT

 WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit) > 0
 BEGIN
  SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit)  
  SELECT @name = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)

  INSERT INTO @returnList 
  SELECT @name

  SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)
 END

 INSERT INTO @returnList
 SELECT @stringToSplit

 RETURN
END
```

then use `CROSS APPLY` to get `count` by the name.

```
SELECT Name,count(*)
FROM T t1 CROSS APPLY fn_split(t1.col) v
group by Name
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=faad7b7a0b7ae5a22507592edda82ab8)

Comment: @user2443401 No problem glad to help:)

Comment: Cheers! I was using same approach! but I failed to get count by the name! you deserve upvotes! :D

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a function  same as below.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[split](
    @delimited NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @delimiter NVARCHAR(100)
) RETURNS @t TABLE (id INT IDENTITY(1,1), val NVARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @xml XML
    SET @xml = N'<t>' + REPLACE(@delimited,@delimiter,'</t><t>') + '</t>'
    INSERT INTO @t(val)
    SELECT  r.value('.','varchar(MAX)') as item
    FROM  @xml.nodes('/t') as records(r)
    RETURN
END
```

then Eg.

```
create table #Fruits (
  id int identity(1,1),
  string nvarchar(100)
)

insert into @Fruits (string) values ('Apple,Mango'), ('Orange'), ('Apple')

select val,val+'(' +cast(count(val) as varchar(10))+')'val
from @Fruits 
  cross apply dbo.split(string,',') 
group by val
```